# Compare two expressions in term of two variables

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials, substitution, number-comparison

Suppose that$a>0$ and $b>0$. Compare two numbers:
$$
S_1=a^2b^2(a^2+b^2-2), \quad S_2=(a+b)(ab-1).
$$
**My attempt.** If $a=b$, then we have 
$$
S_1-S_2=2a^4(a^2-1)-2a(a^2-1)=2a(a-1)^2(a+1)(a^2+a+1)\geq 0.
$$
Therefore, we think that $S_1\geq S_2$.

Comment: If $a=b$ then $S_1=a^4(2a^2-1)$ which is not what you wrote.

Comment: @David Thank you. I fixed my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll prove that $S_1\geq S_2$.

Indeed, let $a+b=2u$ and $ab=v^2$, where $v>0$.

Thus, by AM-GM $u\geq v$ and we need to prove that
$$v^4(4u^2-2v^2-2)\geq2u(v^2-1)$$ or $f(u)\geq0,$ where
$$f(u)=2v^4u^2-(v^2-1)u-v^6-v^4.$$
But by AM-GM 
$$f'(u)=4v^4u-v^2+1\geq4v^5-v^2+1=2u^5+2u^5+3\cdot\frac{1}{3}-v^2\geq$$
$$\geq5\sqrt[5]{(2u^5)^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3}-v^2=\left(5\sqrt[5]{\frac{4}{27}}-1\right)v^2>0,$$
which says that $f$ increases.

Id est, $$f(u)\geq f(v)=2v^6-(v^2-1)v-v^6-v^4=v^6-v^4-v^3+v=v(v^2-1)(v^3-1)\geq0.$$
Done!